# ruby : regex replace string beetween two char [ ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

i want to remove text in string beetween [ ]:
ex:

```
Hello everyone [hi hi], hello world [ha ha]
```

result:

```
Hello everyone, hello world
```

i use

```
string.gsub!(regex-here , ' ')
```

help me define a  regex-here.

Comment: Can the `[]` be nested? If not, it is a simple task. Haven't you tried anything yet? What exact issue do you have with your code?

Comment: You won't get that result just by removing the text between `[]` (and the `[]` itself).

Comment: By the way, the musician's name is spelled "beethoven".

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you do not want leading/trailing spaces to be left in the result:

```
▶ str = "[ho ho] Hello everyone [hi hi], hello world [ha ha]"
▶ str.gsub /\s*\[.*?\]\s*/, ''
#⇒ "Hello everyone, hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\s*\[.*?\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM6gB3/1)

Explanation:

`\[`: matches `]`
`.*?`: matches any character as few times as possible, expanding as needed

Comment: This won't remove `[...]` at the beginning of a string.

Comment: 1. `"Hello everyone [hi hi], hello world [ha ha]".gsub!(/(\[.*?\])/,'') #=> "Hello everyone , hello world "` is not the desired result. 2. The capture group is not needed (`/\[.*?]\]/` is sufficient). 3. "matches any character as few times as possible" implies that no character would be matched. I know what you mean but you haven't expressed it correctly.